# Decoding of char array data

Tags: utf-8, uwp, c++-cli

I have a mesh from which I need to read the vertex positions of  but I can just get a buffer with that data, which I seemingly can get as an utf-8 char array.

Currently I'm getting the data from the buffer into the array I metioned and wirte it into a char* but i can't get the decoding correctly or so it seems.

The following code reads the dara from the buffer:

```
char* GetDataFromIBuffer(Windows::Storage::Streams::IBuffer^ container)
{
   unsigned int bufferLength = container->Length;
   auto dataReader = Windows::Storage::Streams::DataReader::FromBuffer(container);
   Platform::Array<unsigned char>^ managedBytes =
    ref new Platform::Array<unsigned char>(bufferLength);
   dataReader->ReadBytes(managedBytes);

  char * bytes = new char[bufferLength]; 

  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < bufferLength; i++)
  {
    if (managedBytes[i] == '\0')
    {
        bytes[i] = '0';
    }
    else
    {
        bytes[i] = managedBytes[i];
    }
  }
}
```

I can see the data in debug mode but i need a method to make it readable and write it into a file, where i can copy the mesh data and draw the mesh in a seperate program.

The following image shows the array data which can be seen in the array:
[debug mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Olfvx.png)

Comment: This seems to be C++/CLI, and not C++. Please tag your questions correctly.

Comment: I only care about the C++ part, so I updated the code example to make it clear. The important part for me is to get the managedBytes in a char* which represents the data I need.

Comment: Still, you need to tag the language, that you are using. Since `Windows::Storage::Streams::IBuffer^` is invalid C++, but is valid C++/CLI - you can't be using C++.

Comment: Thank you, will do it right next time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be careful not to mix up text encoding and data types.

char is a type often used for buffers because it has the size of a byte, but that doesn't mean that the data contained in the buffer is text.

Your debug view seem to confirm that the data inside your buffer is not text, because when interpreted as text, it gives weird characters such as 'ÿ', '^', etc...

UTF-8 is a way to encode unicode text, so it has nothing to do with binary data.

You need to find a way to cast your buffer data info the internal type of the data, it should be documented where you got that data (maybe it's just an array of floats ?)

Comment: Thanks, that sounds like an approach I should look into. So far there was no direct way to save it to an float array but I will see if I get it to work.